# ERROR: function(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 function the first start with the angular controller and the second load a state from the data base, the problem is because JavaScript is asynchronous the variable `$scope.info.loadState` was undefined when i use in the function, searching I find the function `.done` how a solution to this problem, but now  when start the controller get the following error `Error: loadByIdAssetState(...) is undefined`
the function code are the following

```
angular.module('assetModule')
  .controller('assetEditCtrl', ['selectedService','assetRESTService'
                           ,'assetStateRESTService','$location', '$modal' 
                           ,'$scope', assetEditCtrl]);

function assetEditCtrl (selectedService, assetRESTService, assetStateRESTService, $location, $modal, $scope) {
        $scope.file = {};
        $scope.data = {};
        $scope.info = {};
initCtrl();

function initCtrl() {
  $scope.info.selected = {};
  if(selectedService.getSelected() != undefined){
    $scope.file.asset = selectedService.getSelected();
    selectedService.setSelected(undefined);
    $scope.info.loadState = loadByIdAssetState($scope.file.asset.assetState_id)
    .done(function(state) {
      console.log(state);
      $scope.file.asset.stateName = state.state;
      return state;
    });
    console.log($scope.info.loadState);
    $scope.file.asset.stateName = $scope.info.loadState.state;
  }

}


function loadByIdAssetState(stateId) {
  assetStateRESTService.getByIdAssetStates(stateId)
    .then(function(state) {
      console.log(state);
      $scope.info.loadStateReady = true;
      return state;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

 }
}
```

`getSelected` is a service that return the selected asset, the asset have assetState_id, I want the name to this state

Comment: can you provide full code?

Comment: I edit the code, for now it's only one assignation

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've forgot to inject `loadByIdAssetState` into your controller, you must do this in order to use it. Do this:

```
 function initCtrl(loadByIdAssetState) {
    $scope.info.loadState = loadByIdAssetState($scope.file.asset.assetState_id).done(function(state) {
      console.log(state);
      $scope.file.asset.stateName = state.state;
      return state;
    });
    console.log($scope.info.loadState);
    $scope.file.asset.stateName = $scope.info.loadState.state;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if `loadByIdAssetState` is defined in the same controller why i have passed for parameter? if I pass the function hw param get the following error `loadByIdAssetState is not a function`

Comment: You're gonna have to show more code because we can't see the whole picture.

Comment: I edit the question with the complete controller, the question was poorly formulated offer one apologized